# SQL Server gets Access Denied when attempting to delete old log shipping transaction log backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm having a problem with old Log files not being deleted after the retention period expires in a Log Shipping Job (Error Message Below)

The SQL Servers Service account obviously has access to the folder since it is able to create the backup files. I suspicion is that perhaps the delete part of the Job executes under the credentials of the SQL Agent rather than the credentials of the SQL Server Service. However I can't find any information to confirm this hypothesis.

```
2016-07-02 17:15:01.73  Deleting old log backup files. Primary Database: 'DBNAME'
2016-07-02 17:15:01.77  *** Error: Could not delete old log backup files.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2016-07-02 17:15:01.77  *** Error: Access to the path '\\SERVERNAME\LOGFILEBACKUPPATH' is denied.(mscorlib) ***
2016-07-02 17:15:01.78  The backup operation completed with errors. Primary Database: 'DBNAME', Log Backup File: '\\SERVERNAME\PATHTOLOGGILE' 
2016-07-02 17:15:01.79  ----- END OF TRANSACTION LOG BACKUP   -----
```

Comment: Yes, your logshipping agent jobs runs under SQL Server agent account. Make sure your agent account has write access to the backup share and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; transaction logs where piling up and we had to delete them manually. Eager to find a solution, all searches was leading to a blind end. By coincident I found this page after I applied the solution; like SQLPRODDBA says, you need to give the proper access to the SQL Server Agent account as well.

Not just the SQL Server service account like Microsoft states.

[image]

After adding access to the SQL Server Agent account, files where deleted as expected.